# Generate async-only interface from wsdl?

Tags: .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

Is there any way to generate *only* the task based async methods with svcUtil?

The reason is I have given WSDLs which I need to implement as a service. The easiest way seems to be to just add them as a service reference and implement the generated interface as a service. This works great as long as you stay synchronous but for async it obviously generates two methods with the same `OperationContract`, which is invalid.

Other ways of fixing this dilemma are appreciated as well of course. My constraint is that I have to stick to the given WSDL files, so I can't generate the WSDL from the interface (yay -.-)

Regarding the duplicate claim: nope. This does not help at all. I played around with ConcurrencyMode and Task-based services now and there is a huge difference in performance between the two. For example: Shooting with 100 threads against either of these implementations,

```
public async Task<SomeObj> GetSomeObj(SomeReq request)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return SomeObj();
}
```

performs much better than

```
public SomeObj GetSomeObj(SomeReq request)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return new SomeObj();
}
```

no matter what ConcurrencyMode is selected in the ServiceBehavior (which, funny enough, had only very little influence on the performance).

So the question still stands: how to generate a task-based service contract from a WSDL, because we can clearly show that they have superior performance (both when it comes to startup behaviour as well as predictability of runtime performance).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Service References. No invalid code gets generated. Both *proxy* methods call the same service method. Why do you think there is anything invalid? Did you encounter a different problem, and think that WSDL or svcutil is broken? (it isn't).

Comment: Do you have actual code that demonstrates a problem or just assumed that two proxy methods can't call the same service operation?

Comment: `add them as a service reference and implement the generated interface as a service.` No, that's wrong. Service references generate *client proxies*. If you want to generate service classes you should use `svcutil` directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos alright, will look into that. Was just hoping I could get around this easily ... not the one who started doing it that way ;)

Comment: Whoever started using the client proxy generation command for service implementations probably had to *delete* the client-only code. Not my definition of "easily".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nothing to delete, really. Works out of the box.

Comment: What's the point of this question then??? You said that using the client-side interfaces in a *service* implementation has issues, which it does. That's not "works out of the box"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF / svcutil in .NET 4.5 generates unusable code by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914303/wcf-svcutil-in-net-4-5-generates-unusable-code-by-default)

Comment: Check the duplicate and have in mind that `async/await` doesn't mean asynchronous service operations

Comment: I saw that one but it kinda has the inverse problem from what I'm actually looking for. Also, what I wanted to say regarding your other post that you deleted: The solution is a test fixture for load tests which also does artificial delays, at which point under high load it craps out if it's not async (which was hacked into a few places manually to prevent that)

Comment: I fully understand what you say and what you are trying to do. I've been working with WCF since day 1. Check the duplicate, because it already contains anything discussed here. Also check how WCF handles concurrency, otherwise you'll end up with a single thread awaiting for some asynchronous database call and a huge input queue. Although it sounds like you already hit that one

Comment: Well, a colleague did at least ;) I'm just the poor sucker who can fix it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos see edit ... Tasks are really much preferable in the scenario as can be easily benchmarked, so the question stands: how can svcutil create a task-based interface out of a wsdl?

Comment: Which I did ... as the text clearly states.

Comment: no, you just can't read

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752260(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, you just can't read ... I tried the different concurrency modes (as the post says), they do not greatly affect how this scenario behaves. Using tasks does however.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to make WCF expose the exact same class that svcutil generates as a client? Are you open to workarounds and other ways to achieve your goal?

Comment: @usr well, the task-based interface would be what I need ... because svcutil can only do synchronous it seems with the `serviceContract` flag (and the one generated via a client proxy obviously has both sync and async, which bind to the same action, which in turn is not allowed). My current line of thought is writing some sort of wrapper which could also centralize the ~~timeout~~ sleep/delay value (a definite win)

Comment: Or copy out the interface and classes and manually delete the sync methods?; Sometimes it's also a solution to just increase the thread pool limits. As long as you don't have 1000 concurrent requests in flight this can be a quick solution. You can eliminate startup problems that way, too. WCF does not apply any artificial concurrency limit except for the configured limits. You can try this with TP.SetMinMaxThreads(1000).

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that option, I'd just hoped we can have it automatically somehow (not that we update that thing that often ... but you know, lazyness ;)) ... as for the threadpool -> that thing runs on some crazy large-scale setups sometimes I am told (our devops love to use their uber-premium-MS contract for joint load testing in Redmond ... not that I'd get invited), which is where they ran into the problem in the first place.